# Volume Check Failed error while running Data Migration

Tags: magento-1.7, magento2-migration-tool

I am facing below error when i migrate from CE1.7.0.2 to CE2.0.7,

```
[2016-06-03 05:34:59][ERROR]: Incorrect value: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_block_proportions in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=umm_cat_block_proportions
[2016-06-03 05:34:59][ERROR]: Incorrect value: ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_categorylabel in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=umm_cat_label
[2016-06-03 05:34:59][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: EAV Step]: failed
```

I checked the `config.xml` file:

```
<models>
    <ultramegamenu>
        <class>Infortis_UltraMegamenu_Model</class>
    </ultramegamenu>
</models>
```

Can anyone help me with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,

We can ignore these attributes by adding its code to etc/ce-to-ce/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist 
You can find the code of attribute in the error message